# sctp_send() failure while sending sctp data

Tags: linux, rhel7, sctp

The SCTP association has been established between the 2 nodes.
Node 1 has been able to send SCTP data to Node 2.
But while Node 2 tries to respond to Node 1 data sctp_send() fails with error code EINVAL.
But SCTP HEARTBEAT and HEARTBEAT ACK is getting exchanged between the nodes.
Please tell me how to debug SCTP Data transmission error.

Comment: Looks like EINVAL is not related to the association state, but rather how you using the API. Can you provide a sample of your code?

Comment: retVal = sctp_send(iActualSocFD,&event->data[sz],(size_t)event->len,(struct sctp_sndrcvinfo *) &sinfo,MSG_NOSIGNAL);
if (retVal == -1)
{
    LOG4CPLUS_FATAL(log,"Unknown Error"<<errno<<"SD"<<iActualSocFD)   
}
Its the same piece of product code which was working (sctp_send() successful) when  it was compiled on RHEL 6 but now failing after upgrading to RHEL 7.6 .The network entity to whom the sctp packet is being sent is on RHEL 6 platform.Whether this is creating any issue ?I suppose backward compatibility should be supported.